# Application of Cauchy-Schwarz with Sobolev norms

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality, partial-differential-equations, inner-products

I'm working through the problems in the initial value formulation chapter in Wald's *General Relativity*.

A short summary of the problem. I have to show that $$\sup_{x\in A}|f(x)|\le C||f||_{A,k}$$ where $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies the uniform interior cone condition, $C$ is a constant, $k>n/2$ is an integer and $||.||_{A,k}$ is the Sobolev norm. Let $Q$ denote the solid closed cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of height $H$ and solid angle $\Omega$, with vertex at the origin. Let $\psi:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^\infty$ function with $\psi(r)=1$ for $r<H/3$ and $\psi(r)=0$ for $r >2H/3$. I have shown that
$$\tag{1}f(0)=C_1\int_{Q\subset\mathbb{R}^n} r^{k-n}\frac{d^k}{dr^k}(\psi f)\,dx$$
The hint says to show
$$\tag{2}|f(0)|\le C||f||_{Q,k}$$
using Cauchy-Schwarz. From this I can obtain the final result using the uniform interior cone condition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I should be using Cauchy-Schwarz with the $L^2$ inner product, not the Sobolev one. I can write
$$f(0)=C_1\langle r^{k-n},\partial_r^k(\psi f)\rangle_{L^2}$$
and thus
$$\tag{3}|f(0)|\le C_1 ||r^{k-n}||_{L^2}\cdot ||\partial^k_r(\psi f)||_{L^2}$$
For the first factor I get
$$||r^{k-n}||_{L^2}=\int_Q |r^{k-n}|^2\,dx=\int_Q r^{2k-2n}\,dx=\int_Q r^{2k-2n}r^{n-1}\,drd\Omega=C_2$$
a constant, iff $k>n/2$. Putting this into (3), I get
$$\tag{4}|f(0)|\le C_3||\partial^k_r(\psi f)||_{L^2}$$
I can obtain (2) by showing that
$$||\partial^k_r(\psi f)||_{L^2}\le C_4 ||f||_{Q,k}$$
Intuitively, this is clear, because $||f||_{Q,k}$ contains "more terms" which are all positive. But my problem then lies with the equals in $\le$. I don't see how it could be anything other than strictly larger, but since I'm using my gut here, I could very well be wrong.

EDIT 2: I guess the equality could hold based on the precise form of $\psi$ perhaps, but I'm still not sure.

Comment: Since the problem asks you to prove $\leq$, I'm not sure why it matters whether equality is ever satisfied (which would depend among other things on whether the constants that you've chosen are sharp). Are you just wondering about it out of curiosity?

Comment: @epimorphic: Well I'm not convinced of the $\le$ anyway. I don't see a rigorous way of proving it.